# Using JWT for Loopback authentication

Tags: node.js, jwt, loopbackjs, passport.js

I'm trying to understand how I can fit a custom JWT routing into loopbacks security model. My application has an authentication "dance" involving SMS that results in a valid JWT token using the [excellent description](https://jwt.io/introduction/). I'm using the [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and things work as expected. After obtaining the token my angular.js client sends the token with each request in the `Authorisation: JWT ..token..` header (found conflicting documentation, one says JWT, one Bearer, but I can figure that out).

Now I want to make use of the token inside a loopback application. I'd like to use the ACL system loopback provides. I did read the following resources:

- [Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)
- [Loopback, loggin in users](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Logging+in+users)
- [Third-party login (Passport)](https://docs.strongloop.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=3836277)
- [Loopback, making authenticated requests](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Making+authenticated+requests)
- [Passport strategy for JWT](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt)
- [Loopback OAuth2.0 source](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2-loopback.js)
- [Loopback satelizer](https://github.com/cosmojs/loopback-satellizer)

And I'm not clear what my next steps are. I have working:

- User 'login' - generating a JWT
- User login using username/password (to be retired)
- Working ACL implementation in loopback (when I access an ACL protected resource I get, as expected a 4xx error)
- My JWT token properly (?) in the  header of the request

I need:

- based on the JWT token a valid user with roles compatible to loopback ACL

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Thx for reminding me. Yes I did. Answer below

Comment: The authentication scheme for JWT tokens is "Bearer".

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be much simpler that I though it would be. For starters loopback does use its own jwt webtokens to keep a (stateless) user session. After establishing identity (in my case extracting the mobile number from my JWT token) I just need to lookup the member and generate the loopback native JWT token. My endpoint definition was this:

```
  Member.remoteMethod(
    'provideSMSToken', {
      accepts: [{
        arg: 'mobilenumber',
        type: 'string',
        description: 'Phone number including +65 and no spaces'
      }, {
        arg: 'token',
        type: 'string',
        description: 'the token received through SMS'
      }],
      returns: {
        arg: 'token',
        type: 'string'
      },
      description: 'provide SMS token to confirm login',
      http: {
        path: '/smsauthenticate',
        verb: 'post'
      },
      isStatic: true
    }

  );
```

and the `provideSMSToken` function like that:

```
 // Exchange the SMS Token with a login token
  Member.provideSMSToken = function(mobilenumber, token, cb) {
    var app = Member.app;
    // CHeck if the token does exist for the given phone number
    // if yes, check for the respective memeber

    if (!app.smsVerificationToken || !app.smsVerificationToken[mobilenumber] || app.smsVerificationToken[mobilenumber] !== token) {
      var wrongToken = new Error("Wrong or missing token");
      cb(wrongToken, "Wrong or missing token");
    } else {
      var timetolive = 86400;
      Member.lookupByPhone(mobilenumber, function(err, theOne) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err, "Sorry, no such member here!");
        } else {
          // We can provide a token now for authentication
          // using the default createAccessToken method
          theOne.createAccessToken(timetolive, function(err, accesstoken) {
            cb(err, accesstoken);
          })
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Works like a charm

Comment: I'm using loopback but it's not using JWT and I've been looking to implement them. Did you have to configure something or it uses JWT out of the box?

Comment: Loopback authentication tokens are JWT.

Comment: Loopbacks or gateway?  Because my db is storing tokens and they dont have the normal jwt structure.

Comment: JWT is encoded (not encrypted) signed arbitrary content. There is no such thing as 'normal' structure. But you might want to ask a new question and propose all moving parts. When you provide incomplete information you won't get the answer you are looking for

Comment: JWT's have a "normal structure". It consists of a header, payload and signature, separated by dots - see https://jwt.io . The access-token used in our LoopBack app doesn't have three sections and don't decode to any payload and are not stateless as they are stored in the DB. (At least the implementation that I'm working on). I also don't see anything in the loopback docs about JWT. Any chance you could send some links to something that explains how to use JWT's in loopback?